# Showing Error Name (by function) in Angular

Tags: angular, error-handling

I am trying to take in a textarea, like so:

```
  <textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Elaborate your question.

Comment: @SunilSingh I would like to display the name if the function if it applies to the string

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a property to hold the error Messages getting in each rule when it fails. For example

create a global property on your component

```
errorMessages:Array<string>=[];
```

On each rule , push the error messages when it fails

```
   checkTabsNewLines = ( str ) => {
        const reN = /[\n]/mg;
        const reT = /[\t]/mg;
        if (((str || '').match(reN) || []).length === ((str || '').match(reT) || []).length - 1) {
          return true;
        } else {
         this.errorMessages.push("checkTabsNewLines thrown an error");
          return false;

        }

      }
```

On your html , you can simply iterate and show the error messages

```
<div [hidden]="checkValid()" class="error-message">
                <span [innerHTML]="error"  *ngFor="let error of errorMessages"></span>
            </div>
```

You can clear the error based on your logic by set the array as empty

```
this.errorMessages=[];
```

> Note : You can also use string instead of Array , if you have only one
>   error to show in the UI

Answer (score 0):

You need to make few of changes in your html and ts file.

> 1. Change in html

innerHTML is not required. If you have html content then you can use innerHTML instead.

```
<div [hidden]="checkValid()" class="error-message" [innerHTML]="errorMessage">
       {{ errorMessage }}
 </div>
```

> 2. Change in ts

```
  errorMessage = ""; <-- You can make it array if you want to store multiple errors.
  checkTabsNewLines = ( str ) => {
    const reN = /[\n]/mg;
    const reT = /[\t]/mg;
    if (((str || '').match(reN) || []).length === ((str || '').match(reT) || []).length - 1) {
      this.errorMessage = "It has tab lines";
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  }

  checkTabsNewLinesSuggestedQ = ( str ) => {

  if(true){ . //set the message if function returns true.
    this.errorMessage = "checkTabsNewLinesSuggestedQ message"; /<--set message
  }     

  ........return false/true}

  checkEmptyVal = ( str: string ) => {
    if(true){ . //set the message if function returns true.
      this.errorMessage = "checkEmptyVal message"; /<--set message
    } 
    ....... return false/true
  }
```